# Remove characters from the beginning of a string

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can I remove the first letters in my string when I don't know how many '0' characters I have at the beginning of my string. Additionally the '0' should not removed from the string when it is not in the beginning.

For instance, remove `0` from:

```
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000The sun is going up at 06:30pm


00000000000000000000000000000Finally it is over
```

to get:

```
The sun is going up 06:30pm
Finally it is over
```

Comment: @RNar you should post that as a solution.

Comment: @NathanielFord it was bound to be a dup, I just couldnt find the dup

Comment: I noticed that str.lstrip('0') would remove all '0' but when I have a number at the end of my string it should be not removed.

Comment: @SamS. Sounds like you need to refine your problem statement, including fleshing out your test cases. Also note that `lstrip` only removes from the left of the string, not the end. It is different than the `strip` function.

Comment: `lstrip()` will indeed not remove anything from the end of the string, so it should be perfect for your needs.

Comment: okay thx :) seems it works